# How to Query database for certain range of dates

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am in need to query mysql to get details of a certain range. Say, I have a range from

`'2/1/2013' to '8/1/2013'`,  which is 7 days.

To get this range I can just use "from","to" in mysql query. 
But, how should I use query to get result for certain number of same range.

Say if I need to get next 3 set of results then, Query should bring result in 3 columns of results in range,

```
'2/1/2013' to '8/1/2013'
'9/1/2013' to '15/1/2013'
'16/1/2013' to '22/1/2013'`.
```

As I need 3 results in 3 rows for same conditions, is this possible by using a single query?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: @SalmanA I need 3 rows of results with each passed through 3 ranges. Say for 1st range = count is 8,2nd range = count is 12,3rd range = count is 20

Comment: @Ganesh: see if the answer that uses UNION helps (you probably need a GROUP BY as well).

Answer (score 1):

[Use This Link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187922.aspx)

```
test_expression [ NOT ] BETWEEN begin_expression AND end_expression
```

Answer (score 0):

why do you not use the `Between` keyword as in

```
select * from table where TO >= '18/03/2011' AND TO <= '18/09/2011'
union
select * from table where TO >= '18/01/2011' AND TO <= '18/02/2011'
union
select * from table where FROM >= '18/03/2011' AND FROM <= '18/09/2011'
union
select * from table where FROM >= '18/01/2011' AND FROM <= '18/02/2011'
```

Comment: "Between" fetches only one single result between that range. But I need individual results in each range for the given conditions

Comment: use in combination with `union` - answer updated

Answer (score 0):

Use this query and replace your table name

```sql
SELECT * FROM table WHERE from >= '2013-01-02' AND to < '2011-01-08' 
UNION SELECT * FROM table WHERE from >= '2013-01-09' AND to < '2011-01-15' 
UNION SELECT * FROM table WHERE from >= '2013-01-16' AND to < '2011-01-22';
```

Comment: As I mentioned in question "from", "to" gives result for single range of dates. I need multiple range of dates in single query

Comment: Use UNION and add multiple queries.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to get Your expected result in single query:-

```
select * from tableName where ((dt between '2/1/2013' AND '8/1/2013') 
    or (dt between '9/1/2013' AND '15/1/2013') 
    or (dt between '16/1/2013' AND '22/1/2013'));
```